# User input in linux bash to check against a list and respond with result

Tags: bash

I am trying to get bash to ask for a user input from read and to check against a file or list of files, then respond with the result from that chesk. This is as far as I have gotten as of yet...

```sh
read -p "what are we looking for?" RESP
if [ "$RESP" = sed -n ${some line from inside file} ./file | 
then do "returned variable from file"

else
echo "You need more bash programming"
```

I know I am very new here but I cant figure it out, 
what ever the response is needs to be check against a file (what inside the file)- line by line then return an associated variable of that line

say like

```
"RESP"=line 3(or any line that matches) of ./this_file 
return "var1" of that line
Do "var1"

fi
```

Is this the way to do this what would this code look like in simple bash
I am so lost please help

example:

line1:"please open google" "var1[open http:www.google.com]

pass "var1" to bash

Comment: Is `./this_file` the same as `./file`?  How is a `var1` associated with a line? It would help if you provided specific examples to show what it is that you really want.

Comment: ahhh yes, the "var1" should be an associated variable from the line in the file.... i dont know how to do this.. i am assuming it would look like this        var1: please open google

Comment: edited the main post.....looking for a fix to pass an input "resp" to check against the lines of a file then return the "var1" associated with that line..... i hope that is clearer..  then execute the var1... or in this case,  open google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file, I suggest a format like:

```
please open google|open http:www.google.com
```

Here the response is everything before the vertical bar.  Your `var1` is everything after the vertical bar.  (If you had more vars to put on that line, separate them with more vertical bars.)

As for the script, here is a start:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "what are we looking for? " response
action="$(awk -F\| -v r="$response" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file)"
eval "$action"
```

The read command gets the input.  (It is best practice to use lower case for your shell variables so that you don't accidentally overwrite something important.)

The line with `awk` extracts the action from the first line in the file that begins with `response|`.  It assumes that everything after that first vertical bar is your command.

The last line above executes `action`.  It does this with `eval`.  The use of `eval` requires some level of trust.  As you refine your design, you should eliminate the use of `eval`.

#### Using a different field separator

If we use `@` in place of `|` for the field separator, then `file` would have lines like:

```
please open google@open http:www.google.com
```

The code needs a single change:

```
read -p "what are we looking for? " response
action="$(awk -F@ -v r="$response" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file)"
eval "$action"
```

Comment: hmmmm ok would it be easyer to use speacial characters to delineate between line:"response" and " action" how would we understand the usage of " | "..... the pipe in this context how does that work? i dont understand....

Comment: If i say "give me google" and is this suppose to take that as "response" look for it in these files" file1, file2, file 3" then pass that line of everything past " | " into a "var1".....?

Comment: @RobLooman As used here, `|` is just a character (not a pipe).  I chose it simply because it was unlikely that you would use it as part of a user "response".  Any other unusual character could be used in its place, maybe a colon or semicolon or at-sign, etc.

Comment: @RobLooman Yes, if the user types in "give me google", then the code selects the stuff past `|` on the "give me google" line and assigns it the variable `action`.  (I chose `action` as the name, rather than `var1`, because it seems more descriptive.)

Comment: hmmm i re-read your other posts it all looks good and i will implament it asap,   question for you, you said "The line with awk extracts the action from the first line in the file that begins with response|. It assumes that everything after that first vertical bar is your command."  i would need this to read the whole file  about 10-50 lines is there another way to make it work?.... thank you again

Comment: it looks for the "response" given by user in the whole file all lines not just the first then does "action" acordingly

Comment: @RobLooman As written, it reads the file up to and including the first line whose first field matches `response`.  Because of the `exit` command, it reads no further.  It could be made to work differently.  How would you want it to work?

Comment: ok trying to implament, in the file section how are the list of files formated is it "file1, file2, file3)" or is there another situation? i should know of

Comment: @RobLooman As written, the response, command pairs are in a single file called `file`.  If they are split among multiple files, just supply them space-separated like:  `action="$(awk -F\| -v r="$response" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file1 file2 file3)"`

Comment: well its not working, i am getting this response....  line 28: -v: command not found
awk: option -F lacks argument

Comment: code as written by you.... 
read -p "" response
action="$(awk -F|-v r="$response" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' file1)"
eval "$action"

Comment: @RobLooman You need to either escape with a backslash, as I did in the code in the answer, or quote the vertical bar so that the shell does not interpret it as a pipe.  Thus `awk -F\| -v ...` Without the escape, the shell thinks that you are piping `awk -F` to the command `-v`.

Comment: example please... and again thank you for your time?

Comment: The code in the answer includes the backslash escape when the vertical bar is used.  (No escape is needed for the `@` version.)

Comment: i got it exactly but i get another error..your code:        
read -p "what are we looking for? " response
action="$(awk -F\| -v r="$response" '$1==r{print $2;exit}' ./file1)"

eval "$action"

Comment: error:   Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

Comment: That error appears to me to be caused by the `open` command.  For possible solutions, see: http://superuser.com/questions/477819/how-to-open-a-particular-file-from-a-terminal

Comment: i apreciate your time here but it isnt working and i am more confused them when i started, thank you any way.....BTW there arnt any open commands what are you refering to?

Comment: You wrote "...then execute the var1... or in this case, open google.com"  I used that example in my answer.  That was the `open` command I was referring.  I suggest replacing `eval` with `echo` so you can see what it is trying to do.

Comment: Also, the error you noted was in _line 28_.  That means that you have a much more complicated script than we are running here.  You may want to break your script into parts and check each part separately.